# Genaralisation of ER diagams

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Can Any one explain the difference between using "d" and "o" notations in Generalization & Specialization of ER diagrams. Whether the both notation gives the same meaning or different meanings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you mean? Like an image?

Comment: I have edited my question  hope it clears , what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `o` is for overlapping, meaning an entity type can belong to more than one subtype. In your example, an `Assignment` can involve a `Grade` and/or a `Lab_Session`.

A `d` is for disjoint, meaning an entity type can't belong to more than one subtype. In your example, a `Lecture` can be only one of `Enhancement`, `SpecialDegree` or `GeneralDegree` lectures.